# Copy pasting using Range.Value in VBA formats my text as date. How can I fix this?

Tags: vba, date, text, formatting, copy-paste

I want to copy-paste only the values in a range of cells in Excel.
I am using the assignment method as it is the fastest and perfectly does the job except that it pastes some values which are "12-18" as "18-Dec".

```
sheet1.Range("A1:B100").Value = sheet2.Range("A1:B100").Value
```

I tried to use Range.NumberFormat = "@" to explicitly change the format to Text before copying but it isn't working. Is there any other simple way to do this?

Comment: `Sheet1.Range("A1:B100").NumberFormat = "@"` is working for me

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been answered before ....

```
Sheet2.Range("A1:B100").Copy
Sheet1.Range("A1:B100").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Docu on [PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial)

Comment: Yes, this works but it's not as elegant or as fast. 
I wanted to know if there is any other workaround for this.

Comment: What do you mean, "not elegant and fast"? It works; I can't see how this would be slow and neither that it is not an elegant solution.